# BsonDiscriminator attribute is not working ? (RegisterClassMap does)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to serialize a simple JSON string to a BsonDocument :

```
var st = @"{ ""_t"" : ""Class2"", ""aaa"" : 2 }";
var bsonDocument2 = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(st);
Console.WriteLine(bsonDocument2);
```

Where `Class2` is inherited from `Class1` :

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Class2))]
[BsonDiscriminator(Required = true)]
public class Class1

{

}
[BsonDiscriminator("Class2")]
public class Class2 : Class1
{
    [BsonElement("aaa")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
    public int AAA { get; set; }
}
```

Please notice that I do use  `[BsonDiscriminator("Class2")]` and still I get an error :

> Unknown discriminator value 'Class2'.

However, If I use `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Class2>();` , I  get NO exception and it all works

But I don't want to use code, but an attribute.

**Question:**

Why do I get an exception when using attributes?

The [*docs*](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/) states that it is viable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BsonKnownTypes` attribute makes the difference here. Please note that below like of code works with no exception:

```
var bsonDocument2 = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1>(st);
```

Why? Because you added `BsonKnownTypes` to `Class1` but you couldn't do that for `System.Object`. Moreover when you hover `bsonDocument2` it will be of type `Class2` which means that `_t` works as expected.

Why `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Class2>();` works fine ? Because it registers `Class2` as a known type for all of its parent classes including `object` ([github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/BsonSerializer.cs#L535))

Comment: I thought that .net get's all items as `Object` ( not user's custom type)  and then on runtime emits poly types.... now I see from your answer that they are all being get as a concrete base type , but with instance of poly. Ofcourse - I thank you.